# how to remove an object using action script in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have three images in my form and when the reach 50px in x-axis i want to remove them. I used the below code:

```
onClipEvent (enterFrame) {  
    if (this._x <40){
        this.removeMovieClip();
    }
}
```

But the image is not disappearing. How to remove this object. Thank you

Comment: Your code is purely ActionScript 2 (even 1). Do you want to know how to do that in ActionScript 3, or is your question related to ActionScript 2 ?

Comment: actually I don't know what is actionscript2 or 3 or anything. I just started today working on it

Comment: Ok so I'll just assume you'll be more comfortable with the code you've posted, and I'll edit the AS3 tags for clarification purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also a newbie

maybe removeChild is the one u r looking for,
removeChild(this) or removeChild(myMovieClip)

in AS2, maybe it's the depth issue
this may help somehow
http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?317085-remove-movie-clip-help-remove-child-AS2